# SVG to PDF conversion using TCPDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, svg, tcpdf

I am trying to convert a SVG file to PDF file using TCPDF library in PHP. I have created a SVG file and use PHP to replace text and plan to render the resultant SVG file to PDF file.

Any idea, if TCPDF library supports SVG to PDF conversion. Any pointers in this direction would really help me.

Comment: I think you have already looked http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_058.phps, but in any case it might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, @user3280126, I did have a look, here we are actually inserting an svg file in a pdf. However, I am looking at exporting the svg file into a pdf file.

Comment: As you said TCPDF can insert an SVG file into a (new) PDF and then output the PDF. I don't think it is able to convert or render an SVG as a PDF directly, which is what I understand is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to replace text or render, Once you have created your svg file. All you just need to include tcpdf in your script and create its object like e.g.

```
            require_once(DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/library/Lib/tcpdf/mypdf.php');
            $this->pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
            $this->pdf->AddPage(); // Add page to pdf before addding content
            //There are several other property need to be set on basis of your need
            $this->pdf->ImageSVG('file/mySVGFile.svg', 15, 20, '', '', '',
            '', '', 1, false); // 15,20 are co-ordinate to position graph in pdf
```

Once you added your content to your pdf, Last step comes is to download the pdf using .

```
$this->pdf->Output('my.pdf', 'FD');
```

Feel free to ask for anything you have any query in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$pdf->ImageSVG(VIEW_JS."graph_as_svg/".php", '', '', '210', '100', '', '', '', 0, false);
```

Comment: need more explanations